# How to calculate the hourly average of my data?

Tags: python, csv

I have the data from several sensors stored in a CSV file.

The time resolution is one minute.

The daily average for each sensor was easily calculated.

I need to calculate the hourly average of the data.

**CSV data set format:**

```
5/27/2016 0:00:00 Temperature 39 25
5/27/2016 0:00:00 Pressure    12 39
5/27/2016 0:00:00 Humidity    19 79
.
.
.
5/27/2016 0:01:00 Temperature 39 25
```

- First is date,
- second is time,
- third is parameter name,
- fourth is parameter code, and
- last one is value.

**Relevant part of my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('2016-05-27.csv')

Count_Row=df.shape[0] #gives number of row count

print("The number of rows is", Count_Row)

Parameter_code = 11201
timestamp= []
Par_value = []

n = 0
for rown in range(0,Count_Row):
   if df.iloc[rown,3] == Parameter_code:
       temp = df.iloc[rown, 4]
       if temp != 'nan':
           Par_value.append(float (temp))
           timestamp.append(df.iloc[rown, 1])
           n += 1

print("total sapmles", n) 

print (timestamp)
daily_avg = np.average(Par_value)        
print("The daily average ", daily_avg)
```

**Question:** Is there any method to this hourly averaging?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need avoid loops in pandas, because slow and use:

- add parameter `name` for columns names and `parse_date` for datetimes to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
- filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)
- [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) and aggregate `mean`, `NaN`s are omit by default

---

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""
5/27/2016,0:00:00,Temperature,39,25
5/27/2016,0:00:00,Pressure,12,39
5/27/2016,0:00:00,Temperature,39,NaN
5/27/2016,0:01:00,Temperature,39,25"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
names = ['date','time','name','parameter code','value']
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[['date','time']], names=names)
print (df)
            date_time         name  parameter code  value
0 2016-05-27 00:00:00  Temperature              39   25.0
1 2016-05-27 00:00:00     Pressure              12   39.0
2 2016-05-27 00:00:00  Temperature              39    NaN
3 2016-05-27 00:01:00  Temperature              39   25.0

df = df[df['parameter code'] == 39]
print (df)
            date_time         name  parameter code  value
0 2016-05-27 00:00:00  Temperature              39   25.0
2 2016-05-27 00:00:00  Temperature              39    NaN
3 2016-05-27 00:01:00  Temperature              39   25.0

df1 = df.resample('H', on='date_time')['value'].mean().reset_index(name='mean_val')
print (df1)
   date_time  mean_val
0 2016-05-27      25.0
```

Comment: I am not getting the first part ie. add parameter name for columns names and parse_date for datetimes to read_csv. Should I add manually? I have thousands of those files. Also I could not understand the first part of the code temp =u """ ... """ . I am beginner in python.

Comment: Can you explain more? there are different structures? Or same structure of files?

Comment: Structure is same but the data logger makes file in daily basis. so each day has a different files. So I have the data of 3 years.

Comment: So use `df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(fp, parse_dates=[['date','time']], names=names) for fp in files], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: I tried this code with my data but it was showing error. After debugging, I found out my data have comma (,) at the end of the each line. So to deal with that I modified a line as    names = ['date','time','name','parameter code','value', 'Invalid_column'] . It created a extra column - Invalid_column with all values NaN. However ,my purpose was fulfilled.